# Angular ui.bootstrap datepicker dynamic min-date not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Im using Angular ui.bootstrap datepicker I need to set min date dynamically based on other date I have selected.
Bellow I have added the code that I have tried. Here 'To' date I will be selecting first. Based on 'To' date selected I need to set min date for 'From' date. 'From' date min should be 30 days prier to  date selected in 'To' Date.

JS.

```
$scope.showButtonBar = false;
$scope.disabled = true;
$scope.today = function() {
  $scope.dt;
};
$scope.dtmax = new Date();
$scope.dateformat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
$scope.today();
$scope.showto = function($event) {
  $scope.showdpto = true;
};
$scope.showfrom = function($event) {
  $scope.showdpfrom = true;
};

$scope.setFrom = function(){
  $scope.disabled = false;
  $scope.dfmax = $scope.dt;
  $scope.dfMin = $scope.dt-30; // this is not working
  //$scope.dfMin = ($scope.dt.getDate() - 30); //this is also not working

  $scope.df = "";
  $scope.$apply();
}
$scope.Search = function(){
    console.log($scope.dt);
    console.log($scope.df);
    console.log($scope.dfMax);
  }
```

HTML

```
  From:
  <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateformat}}" showWeeks="false"
         show-button-bar="false" ng-model="df" is-open="showdpfrom"
         max-date="dfmax" min-date="dfMin"
         ng-style="disabled ? {'background-color':'#000'}:{'background-color':'fff'}"/>
  <span>
    <button type="button" ng-disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-default"
            ng-click="showfrom($event)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </button>
  </span>
  TO:
  <input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{dateformat}}" showWeeks="false"
         show-button-bar="false" 
         ng-model="dt" is-open="showdpto" max-date="dtmax"
         ng-change="setFrom()"/>
  <span>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="showto($event)">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
</button>
<button class="btn-confirm" ng-click="Search()">SEARCH</button>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

min-date attribute accepts value as date object, So you need set the value for dfMin as follows.

```
   $scope.dfMin = new Date($scope.dt);
   $scope.dfMin.setDate($scope.dt.getDate()-30);
```

$scope.dfMax works because $scope.dt is already a date object.

Comment: It does not take 30 days prier it takes only 2 days. why so?

Comment: I have updated the answer , Please try and let me know.

Comment: It works only for the current year. If I check for previous years I'm not able to select dates in 'From' date

Comment: I have updated the answer, instead of setting new date, just set to date for mindate - $scope.dfMin = new Date($scope.dt);